¿Desde cuándo un usuario puede borrar el contenido de una respuesta de otro?
Ayer tuve una experiencia muy desagradable. En casi una década que participo denodadamente en este sitio, tratando de ser lo más honesto y servicial que puedo, nunca me había pasado que otro usuario decidiera, por razones que desconozco (¿envidia, frustración?), directamente borrar, mediante la edición, el contenido de una respuesta que elaboré, como siempre lo hago, en forma concienzuda. No solo eso -- también me acusó falsamente de haber calcado otra respuesta (es probable que en alguna otra oportunidad yo mismo haya respondido otra pregunta similar en términos análogos, pero no tengo el tiempo ni el ánimo de buscarla).
Creo que este tipo de accionar, tratándose en lo que a mí respecta de una respuesta coherente, escrita en lenguaje correcto y educado, no debería permitirse y debería ser censurado, máxime si se trata de un usuario cuyo tono muchas veces roza la impertinencia y cuya calidad de respuestas suele ser dudosa, abundando en dislates de tediosa lectura y en serios problemas de puntuación, por mencionar solo algunos aspectos criticables.
El hilo en cuestión es este: "Single negative" en español

Hola, no creo sea necesaria tu pregunta en Meta. En estos caso lo que debes hacer es "flaggear" al usuario con la explicación de lo sucedido  (vandalismo) y los moderadores actuarán al respecto.

Del mismo modo, si un usuario cree que tu respuesta es una copia, solo debe flaggear, ni editarla ni borrarla.

La pregunta apuntaba a saber si estaba permitido que un usuario directamente borrara una respuesta ajena por cualquier motivo y acusara a alguien de calco sin ningún fundamento.

No, es vandalismo. La solución es un flag.

El privilegio de edición no debe ser utilizado para destruir o eliminar contenido del sitio.
Cito lo dicho en el centro de ayuda sobre el privilegio de edición:

When should I edit posts?
Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to edit it, you are encouraged to do so.
Some common reasons to edit a post are:

To fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
To include additional information only found in comments, so that all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
To add related resources or hyperlinks

Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged; try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

Como se puede ver, el privilegio existe para que, de manera colaborativa, podamos mejorar el contenido creado por otros usuarios. Esto no ha cambiado.
Desde mi punto de vista, esta edición es un claro mal uso de dicho privilegio. Hiciste bien en revertirla, de haberla encontrado así al revisar los flags, yo mismo la hubiera revertido.
Dicho todo esto, considero también que es importante el uso correcto de la terminología, para una efectiva comunicación. Por la misma razón, estoy editando la pregunta original, pues la respuesta no fue borrada, sino solo su contenido.
Esta aclaración es importante, pues el borrado de una respuesta es una acción que también existe y que puede ser realizada por la comunidad dentro de sus privilegios de moderación del sitio. Aunque el borrado de una respuesta solo puede hacerse mediante el voto de varios miembros de la comunidad, es mejor evitar la confusión.
